# mb_substr return wrong string length

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, substr

I was using substr for my code to cut exactly 75 characters of my string but I've got some problems with UTF-8 strings that produce characters like "�" so I searched for a solution and found out I could use mb_string but when I use mb_string the string that it returns to me is not 75 characters anymore and its length get change in different strings...

```
$title = "hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé hi mémé ";
if(strlen($title) > 75){
    $title = mb_substr($title , 0 , 72 , 'UTF-8');
    $title = $title."...";
}

echo strlen($title); // 93
```

I think the function add extra data to string that makes its length longer, I dont know but I just want to get a 75 character string , I tried to use lower characters for mb_substr parameter but it doesn't work for every strings

Comment: `mb_` works with multibyte strings, `strlen` does not. Your `strlen` counts bytes, not characters.

Comment: @tkausl thanks for your answer , I'm using this function to send some data to a server that I don't access to it, then how could I calculate how many bytes it return to me to get exactly 75?

Comment: You need to be aware of _bytes_, which is generally universally agreed upon these days and _characters_, which is a higher level concept. In some contexts, including most US English, they are often one-to-one, but this is not universal. If you use `mb_` functions, make sure to use them the whole way through: https://3v4l.org/kb0cT